# Why does the x86 not have an instruction to obtain its instruction pointer?

Tags: instruction-set, design-choices, x86

This has always confused me. Why can you not directly obtain the IP, and instead have to go through some odd assembly hoops such as calling a function whose only purpose is to push its own return address onto the stack?

I'm asking about the historical reason, since this decision was probably made back in the time of the 8086.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136475/discussion-on-question-by-michael-stachowsky-why-does-the-x86-not-have-an-instru).

Comment: Worth noting is that x86-64 does have such an instruction: `lea eax,[eip+0]`

Comment: BTW, there are plenty of other CPUs where you cannot do that directly, either.

Comment: The problem with asking why is that only the engineers that made the decisions really can answer. The rest of us can make guesses: they could not at the time think of any use for it, it would take too many transistors or slow down something, they might be planning for the future with more adress bits or modifiers, they knew of a good workaround, the marketing people did not require it, programmers managed anyway, it might create other problems somewhere, ...

Comment: @ghellquist Many such engineers are still alive. Engineers can be and have been interviewed. Some engineers are interested in the retro scene. Engineers must not bee seen as 100% opaque and inaccessible godlike figures we can never know anything about.

Comment: There'a a huge difference between engineers determining required addressing modes (incl. pc-relative) for e.g. 6809 and engineers creating 8086. The first made a wonderful job (even though their speculation on using purchasable ROMs in designs has not justified), the latter have not properly anticipated the importance of pc-relative addressing.

Comment: To be honest I don't remember any 8bit CPU with a such instruction, including 8080, Z80, 6800, 6502 etc. Due to the history of 8086 it's no surprise to such instruction is missing. I am not perfect sure, but I am afraid that 68000 has no such instruction too... Maybe there is another question on the table: Was there any CPU (8/16bit) with such instruction? (And yes, it's sometimes useful, but not on daily basis.)

Comment: @MartinMaly: On the CDP1802, the program counter is just like any other address register, save only for the fact that its number is stored in the P register.  If one knows which register is being used as the program counter, its value may be captured via GHI/GLO instructions.

Comment: Hardware engineering POV: Why have an instruction (and expend all the resources which that implies: in design, expending an instruction slot, testing in development, QA, production test, etc., all of which, overall, adds some, marginal, increased cost to *every* chip) for something that A) can be done with existing instructions without too much difficulty and which is something that is *very* rarely desired? [Yeah, I know it's CISC, but you've got to draw the line somewhere.]

Comment: @supercat Yes, thank you, I wasn't sure about CDP1802 at the moment I wrote that comment. I have met CDP only for a short time ten years ago...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As *Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen* already [put it nicely](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/447/thorbj%C3%B8rn-ravn-andersen):

**What would you need it for?**

There is almost no practical (*1) need to obtain the PC address at runtime (*2) - it's a value to be obtained during assembly time, provided by Assembler and/or Linker. A simple

```
HERE:   LEA  AX,HERE   ;(*3)
```

will make sure the Assembler and/or Linker puts the actual instruction's address into a register (AX in this case).

Now, if you really want to do the trick, than best do it like it would work with any CPU: *Jump one instruction ahead by using a subroutine call and then pop the return address.*

```
       CALL  NEAR PTR NEXT ; Make sure it's not a far call *4
NEXT:  POP   AX
```

Except, there's a ***major caveat***:

Above is trouble-free only in clean 16-bit code. Different addressing modes may require use of 32-bit registers and more.

Going for tricks like this is a sure way to introduce incompatibilities. It's the old story of programming what you want to do, not how to do it. Letting your tools, compiler/assembler/linker, do the 'dirty' work ensures it gets performed the best possible way.

---

#### Further Reading:

As said, there is no real use for IP being one of the accessible registers; many quite successful architectures (/360, 68k, 8080, 6500, etc) do not have a directly accessible PC. They have at most a PC relative addressing (68k).

The PC is never a 'normal' register but is tied to the basic mechanics of a processor. In fact, it brings a lot of advantages (*4) having it completely separated and not readable, as on 8086 and others. It  offers the most simple way to separate operational housekeeping (like (pre-) fetching) from logical operation. The only use case for storing it is in the case of a subroutine branch. This can be handled keeping a shadow copy of the *next* address to be executed.

Architectures that allow the use of a PC in addressing may need to hold a second shadow copy with the instruction's address, complicating it. Architectures that include the PC in the register set, or use one of their GP registers as PC, need to take care about several constraints (*5). One visible sign is that some RISC implementations do need to use PC relative addressing with a constant offset from the actual location. But there is more.

*Long story short: **Better not care for the PC at all - beside jumping that is.***

---

*1 - The "almost" case is dynamically created code - but even then it would be more appropriate to improve the generator.

*2 - And no, the standard use of `BALR Rx,0` by /370 modules to get a local reference for jumps and constants is an oddity due to there being neither an absolute nor a PC relative addressing, nor the ability to load immediate word (address) values.

*3 - And yes, a `MOV` could be used as well in nearly all (simple) cases. I still prefer the `LEA` as it allows even more weird address generations :))

*4 - It still may run into trouble depending on addressing modes and memory model.

*5 - A complex issue in CPUs with a certain level of asynchronous operation, like having prefetch or speculative operation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136539/discussion-on-answer-by-raffzahn-why-does-the-x86-not-have-an-instruction-to-obt).

Comment: Practically every modern operating system requires such an instruction to implement shared libraries and position-independent code, to the extent of CPU manufacturers heavily optimizing the call/pop instruction sequence, which tended to be very slow as it confuses the return stack cache. Also, one of the major improvements of amd64 over x86 was the addition of rip-relative addressing.

Comment: @RememberMonica Position Independent code does not need to access IP, it only needs IP relative (or entry relative) addressing. Likewise do shared libraries only need it (if at all) during initialization, so again no need to have a dedicated instruction. Adding one would be ISA bloat.

Comment: *\*5* doesn't seem to be used, neither now, nor through the edit history.

Comment: @tevemadar Think I found where it belongs. Thanks

Answer (score 19):

OP specifically clarifies interest in a historical reason. Intel would have to give their exact reasoning but the following points are worth noting.

Intel's 8086 and 8088 were outgrowths of their earlier 8008 and 4004 microprocessors - these architectures all had an address space that required more bits than their 16, 8 or 4-bit data width.

On the other hand, minicomputers of the day, including their microcomputer outgrowths, tended to have an orthogonal approach to registers in which the Program Counter and Stack Pointer were numbered in with the general purpose registers and could be accessed or used in a variety of addressing modes (cf. PDP-11 vs LSI-11 and TI990 vs TMS9900 - both originally true 16-bit architectures addressing 2¹⁶ bytes).

The ability to access the Program Counter was very useful and was a common idiom in accessing parameters and local variables stored with the code, and in implementing Position Independent Code or in contexts relating to linking and/or shifting and/or overlaying code blocks (and there were also various useful use-cases involving self-modifying code and dynamically generated/updated code).

One of the big issues with the PDP-11 and TI990 16-bit architectures, as well as earlier 8-bit and 16-bit microprocessors generally, was the inability to index more than 2¹⁶ units of memory.  The PDP-11 family introduced models with separate Instruction and Data address spaces, while a more general approach introduced segments allowed for separate code and stack segments and multiple data segments - with its segment registers the 8086 was able to address a 2²⁰ physical memory. Segmentation also introduced the ability to provide different Read/Write/Execute permissions for different segments.

This, and the increasing use of recursion (which requires a stack), made it inappropriate to store code and data/parameters/locals together in adjacent addresses and means that addresses can't be interpreted without their segment address. That put an end to much of the need for and utility of direct access to the the Instruction Pointer.

Comment: This is a great answer to the question, with loads of supporting detail. Welcome to RCSE!

Comment: Somewhat misleading arguing. 68k managed to use up to 2^32 bytes without segmentation and also had pc-relative addressing, including the ability to load address from PC to GPR.

Comment: @lvd The 68000 is a couple of generations (a decade and a half) later and one of the first 32-bit microchips (alhough with a 16-bit data bus much as the 8088 is a 16-bit machine like the 8086 but with an 8-bit data bus). So it didn't need segmentation to address 2^32 bytes. Of course, paging is another approach to mapping logical address space into a potentially larger physical address and is easier for compilers to manage (so segmentation is phased out in x64).

Comment: 68000 wad quite contemporary to 8086.

Comment: @DavidMWPowers: In what sense is paging "easier for compilers to manage"?  Having a logical address space that's large enough to allow compilers to *ignore* paging is easy, but if one needs a larger address space segmentation is easier to work with.  The only systems I know of where compilers "manage paging" have very small pages (256 bytes or less), and only allow one page to be active at a time.

Comment: @supercat Segmentation means that that the same 'address' points to different locations and thus pointers are more complex to manage; conversely they also introduce the possibility of two different addresses refering to the same location (aliasing). Although in fact, the main reason for x64 dropping segmentation seems to have been that OS's didn't use it and so the cost wasn't worth it.  As a language developer I'd rather we still had segments irrespective of the matching to a larger address space (and being able to manage paging helps manage expandable arrays more efficiently).

Comment: @DavidMWPowers: Segmentation on 8086 means that pointers generally need to be treated as 32-bit quantities rather than 16-bit quantities, except that operations like pointer addition only need to affect the bottom 16 bits.  As for the possibility that two different segment-offset combinations might access the same storage, that's a non-issue for compilers since any particular region of storage will, within its lifetime, always be accessed using the same segment:offset combination except in cases where it's interacting with outside hardware (and needs to be treated as `volatile` anyway).

Comment: @DavidMWPowers: The 8086 works out especially nicely, in fact, because it's possible to manage memory as a linear collection of 65536 16-byte segments that may be individually available or free.  If one honors a 4096-byte allocation request by allocating a 16-byte header at 0x1234:0 and 4096 bytes from 0x1235:0 to 0x1235:0x0FFF, the header at 0x1234:0 would need to record that the next available segment was at 0x1335:0 and intervening segments were unavailable, but the memory manager wouldn't need to care that user code would access all of those segments using 0x1235:0 to 0x1235:0x0FFF.

Comment: The m68k is not a very good example when you want to boast its linear address space. Because PC-relative addressing on the original 68000 has a 16-bit limit, that tends to create a "floating segment" of +/- 32k for purely relocatable programs. The classic MacOS, for example, knows the notion of a "Code segment" (a separate code resource outside the main segment) and quite some classic Mac development systems limited the size of additional (to "main") code segments to 32k to be able to generate fully relocatable code without a loader (that comforted the fact that early Macs were short on memory

Comment: @tofro: The classic Macintosh had a lot of 32K limitations in situations where the 8088 would have had 64K limitations.  Applications on the Classic Mac used A5-relative addressing for what C would call "static duration" objects.  Incidentally, C compilers for the 68000, especially when using 16-bit `int`, could have really benefited from a `[[ ]]` operator which was like `[ ]`, but with a non-scaled displacement measured in bytes, since `intPtr[i]` would require converting `i` to a 32-bit `int`, and doing a 32-bit add with itself before using it as an index, while a byte-indexed...

Comment: ...operation equivalent to `*(int*)((char*)intPtr + i)` could be done directly if `intPtr` and `i`  were in registers, and even if `i` were unscaled, code equivalent to `*(int*)((char*)intPtr + (i+i))` would handle cases where `i` is always -16384..+16383 faster than any possible code that doesn't explicitly use character-based displacement.  Sure one can use the latter ugly syntax to do the same thing, but it would be easier for a compiler to handle `[[ ]]` operators than try to recognize code patterns using the latter syntax.

Answer (score 16):

So long as a stack exists, the IP address may easily be obtained via the byte sequence "E8 00 00 5B" [`CALL $+3 : POP BX`] because near calls use PC-relative addressing.  On the other hand, the normal state of affairs for position-independent code on the 8086 is to be located at a fixed address within an arbitrary segment, which allows zero-effort relocation on any 16-byte boundary.

Because such methods are available (in particular, the PC-relative addressing that enables this within a code block), there is less need to provide a specific instruction to access the instruction pointer.

Comment: Potential catch-22 in some scenarios: with PIC, you may wish to have your stack set to a fixed offset from your code. Which requires knowing the IP to calculate the load address to set SS appropriately...

Comment: Just a note: *NEVER* do in this way in a real code! The proper way is to all a procedure that contains `mov (esp),reg:ret`

Comment: @lvd Never say Never. The procedureless way is quite proper, and the most efficient way of doing it in certain usecases - e.g. code in *ROM where every byte counted (like on a computer with 2K RAM, 2K ROM and 2K EPROM and no disk, as I had in the late 70s; mid 70s, my machines had <1K).

Comment: As it was already mentioned here, it would cause HW callstack to mispredict ALL returns from the first occurence of such code and up to the eviction of all wrong callstack entries. So it's a strict no-no for any i386 code since the times of pentium-2 (I might be wrong here, but only a little).

Comment: BTW I've just googled that x86 macos did exactly the same: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/what-is-the-reason-for-this-method-to-call-itself which adds up to the long story of idiotic technical decisions in macos (the first being artificial segmentation in early 68000 macoses)

Comment: @lvd: Would performance have been better if code did something like `stc/call/jnc done/mov eax,[esp]/clc/ret/done:`?  As for "artificial" segmentation, I don't see what the objection is, given that it allowed the use of 16-bit branch offsets within segments, and the use of the "A5 world" allowed use of 16-bit data displacements for a program's static data.  Sure it made it necessary to sometimes replace what would have been a large static-duration array with a heap-allocated object, but that was a small price to play in exchange for the improved efficiency one would receive in exchange.

Comment: @supercat: what's the efficiency you're talking about? Not a single dynamic linked list could be made on early 68k macs without double dereferencing addresses through "master pointers" -- provided you've got enough master pointers, which is not always the case! Every time one works with already dereferenced pointers and does function calls, there's a hazard that function call might result in heap 'defragmentation'. All that stuff made both 68k macos programming more cumbersome and the resulting programs slower -- is that an improved efficiency indeed?

Comment: @supercat I didn't get the first part of your comment. What is all that stuff starting from `stc`? If one needs PC value in i386 code, the right way to get that is to call a procedure containing exactly this: `mov reg,[esp]: ret`.

Comment: @lvd: I was thinking that latter approach would require having a routine someplace, but that could easily be worked around by having a relative short branch ahead 3 followed by a RETN instruction (skipped by the branch) and a relative call back 1 (hitting the RETN).

Comment: This answer makes no attempt to address the question "_why is there no direct way to access the instruction pointer?_".  Whilst it might be interesting to show an indirect way to do it, that is an answer to an entirely different question.

Comment: @TobySpeight: The question of whether to support something via "direct" means is usually coupled to the question of whether it can be practically accomplished via other means.

Comment: @TobySpeight: On the Z80, the only call instructions use a fixed target address (either following the opcode or embedded within it), which means one needs to know of a fixed address where one can find or place code to inspect the stack, but on the 8086 one can place the stack-inspection code in the same blob as the call instruction without having to know where it is.  The ability to do that means that direct instruction to access the PC has far less value than it would on e.g. the Z80.

Answer (score 14):

On 8086 the instruction pointer is not a general purpose register you can freely access for reading. On earlier 808x models this was also the case, even though program counter was directly used to fetch instructions without a prefetch queue, and  it was settable via PCHL instruction. Because the CPUs supported natively stack, jumping, and subroutines, the programming model how to write ordinary programs just did not need reading of IP, so opcodes and their parameters could be used for other more useful things. And it is still possible to read the position where the CPU is currently executing indirectly if there is need. At a quick glance, many other CPUs from approximately same era (Z80, 6500, 6800) also don't have an opcode to read PC/IP, likely from the same reason.

The CPU does not directly use the instruction pointer for execution, as the executed instructions are fetched from prefetch queue, and the queue is filled from memory.

The instruction pointer (IP) does not reside on the Execution Unit (EU) side, but on the Bus Interface Unit (BIU) side, with the segment registers.

So just like there is no instruction to directly set/store IP, because a jump or call must clear prefetch queue to make sure instructions are fetched for execution from correct address, there is also no instruction to get/load IP, because it likely won't point to the currently executed instruction.

So, whenever the actual value of IP is needed, such as when CALLing a subroutine to push correct value of IP to stack, the value is adjusted as needed and then stored to memory. So there is some logic to keep track of how the IP should be modified when the value is needed.

But internally, that's how the CPU works according to the user manual, with the IP pointing to the address of memory to be next fetched into queue.

Comment: "[the IP] likely won't point to the currently executed instruction" - The IP associated with the currently executed instruction must exist somewhere, else how could a relative branch work?

Comment: In order for the CPU to be able to correctly process a CALL or INT instruction, it must know the address of the following instruction, even if instructions after that have been fetched and will need to be discarded.  By my understanding, the 8086 maintains a Program Counter within the bus interface, and an Instruction Pointer within the execution unit.  CALL and INT instructions save the Instruction Pointer; control-flow instructions load both the PC and IP with the new address.

Comment: Of course there needs to be some logic how it works. However, the 8086 user manual says the instruction pointer is in the BIU, and it also says the IP points to the next instruction to be *fetched* by the BIU (emphasis from manual). IP is adjusted to point to next instruction to be executed if IP needs to be saved on stack.

Comment: Forgot to mention IP will be adjusted by jumps too. And the prefetch queue is the reason why self-modifying code must ensure that the modified code is not already fetched into queue before modifying the memory. And why "POP CS" did exist but was made undocumented.

Comment: @Justme: That seems a bit weird, since it would require that the BIU either have a full 16-bit ALU to perform relative jumps, or would require that the BIU adjust the PC, transfer it to the main execution unit, have it compute the new address, and send the PC back to the BIU.  Also, what I remember from back in the day is that the reason the IP was called the IP rather than the PC was to distinguish the fact that the PC would often point a few bytes ahead of the IP.

Comment: @supercat The BIU already has to have some kind of adder to generate physical address from segment and offset. Or it may use the EU ALU which is anyway used for EA calculation. Or something different. Based on 8086 manuals, we can't know how exactly it works, it just says the IP is adjusted accordingly. The prefetch queue keeps track how full it is and thus can be used to know how much to adjust. And 8086 has IP, it is not called PC anywhere in docs.

Comment: @Justme: Segment+offset calculations need a 12-bit full ALU plus a 4-bit half adder (one operand plus carry from lower half).  Does the 8086 use a separate ALU for effective address calculations as for other register operations?  I guess it could but that seems surprising.

Answer (score 11):

There's a highly-upvoted comment, also requoted in this question's accepted answer, saying *What would you need it for?*  For what it's worth, here is a real, practical, albeit reasonably obscure example.

Once upon a time I wrote a C interpreter.  One of its goals was to allow interoperation between interpreted and previously compiled code.  It contained its own dynamic linker, so that it could read in object and library files, and call functions in them.  (This is the same sort of thing that `dlopen` does today.)

Besides interpreted code making calls to compiled functions, it was also possible for compiled code to call back to interpreted code.  Without going into all the gory details, this meant that a pointer to the interpreter's data structure describing an interpreted function had to also be usable as an actual function pointer.  This data structure therefore began (that is, at offset 0) with a little data block containing [trampoline code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_(computing)) which was contrived to fire up the interpreter on the just-called function.  And the very first thing the trampoline code had to do was, naturally enough, fetch its own PC, because that value was actually the pointer to the data structure describing the function to be interpreted.  (Needless to say this was long before execute protection on data pages, and stuff like that.)

The first processor I wrote this for was the PDP-11, where I found myself able to do something straightforward like `mov pc,r0`.  Not long after, I ported it to the VAX, which trapped on me when I tried to access my own PC in such a crude and obvious way, but after some digging around I was able to achieve the desired effect via a mild circumlocution such as `lea 0@pc` or something like that.  I was certainly aware that what I was doing was dicey and difficult: the PC is *not* a general-purpose register,   for all the sorts of reasons described in the other answers here. So I wasn't surprised I needed a circumlocution, and I was pleased to find one that worked.

(Later on I managed to port the interpreter, with some new trampoline code, to an 80286 or 80386 under MS-DOS, but I don't remember which instructions I used or how clever I had to be.  Much later I somehow got it working on the same x86-based Mac where I'm typing this today.  The gory, handcrafted trampoline code is gone, replaced by a magic [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/) closure.)

So, anyway, this is an example of why someone might legitimately need — or once have needed — to directly access the program counter.

Comment: Well, nice to know why it would be useful to have such an instruction, but it still does not answer the question why there is no x86 opcode for directly getting the current value of IP, and even without such an instruction, it is easy to indirectly fetch it. Regardless of the CPU architecture, you have to work with the registers and instructions you happen to have.

Comment: [**cont**] If (as is often the case: no reflection on you or the original OP), it's an "X-Y" problem (an OP wants to do "something", and _thinks_ knowing the PC will help), then people may be able to point the OP in better ways of solving the core problem. In your particular case, depending when you asked, you might have been told of `LEA 0@PC`, have been directed to `libffi`, or – indeed – your genuine need might have sparked the development of something like `libffi` in the first place!

Comment: On a side note, I used and use (40+ yrs) Assm as main tool on a plethora of CPUs (pick any), for anything from bare metal to OS development and system routines to accounting applications (Jup, those were the days when adding VAT was done in assembly :)) and never found a generic reason to copy the PC, unless there's a specific CPU related issue - like not having immediate values past a single byte on a /360. If there's a need to do so, then either tools (Assembler/Linker) or more advanced instructions (LEA) will be the way to go.

Comment: Second, I understand why you are proud of your clever hack even though I do not fully understand which original problem you solved (avoiding having to run the compiler?).   I noted, however, that you found the required handcrafted (probably meaning raw assembly) trampoline code difficult to maintain and replaced it.

Comment: Third, "fell into disuse" sounds like it wasn't used by many others than you.  How come?

Comment: Fourth, I agree with Raffzahn that this does not answer the original question at all (which may cause it to be closed and deleted) and therefore is probably better placed somewhere else.  Perhaps on your personal blog with a lot more details?

Comment: I don't understand why the data structure needed to follow the trampoline code rather than the code which *invoked* the trampoline, whose address would be pushed in the stack when the trampoline was called.

Comment: @supercat Not sure I understand the question, and this isn't the place for a long discussion of that pet project, which I've said too much about here already, but what I glossed over is that the interpreter has one global symbol table, containing addresses which can be (a) addresses of data objects, (b) pointers to interpreted-function objects, or (c) compiled functions.  If I say `signal(SIGINT, f)`, where `f` is an interpreted function, the kernel gets a pointer to the interp-function object, which it blindly uses a convention call instruction on, but that works, because of the trampoline.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen It was a toy I wrote for fun, to see if I could. But an interpreter can be very useful. The description at the top of its man page was going to be "Eliminate files x.c from /tmp".  Not sure what a particular printf format does? Just fire up the interpreter and try it. But there were practical uses as well.  For example, my answer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/703141 (though it's hardly Posix-compliant) would be `ci -c 'time(0)'`. And for years I think `~/bin/lseek` was a shell script that invoked `ci` to invoke `lseek`, not the small C program it is today.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen It fell into disuse because that's the fate of many back-burner projects.  Also it was the most rampantly nonportable program I've ever written, and the only one with significant (let alone numerous) scraps of assembler to do things that simply can't be done in C.  But it was just *way* too much work to port it to new platforms.  Eventually, though, libffi came along, which does everything it needs. :-)  And it's occasionally handy for answering C questions on Stack Overflow, because again, I can just type things in, no need to create and compile `x.c`.

Comment: @SteveSummit Thank you.  I was really interested to see if this technique had been absolutely necessary in production and if so, why.   I am fine with this being a toy project you've played with over the years, especially as you decided the approach was unmaintainable and ported it successfully to another technology.  That is not something everyone gets to do!   That said, your description reminded me of https://bellard.org/tcc/ which is a tiny, fast C-compiler compiling to memory, almost giving an interpreter.  You might find it interesting.

Comment: For future readers, this answer have been heavily edited, and many of the comments above (plus some that were deleted) were written in response to an earlier version of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

8086 uses a segmented memory model with the address instructions are fetched from calculated by `CS` * 16 + `IP`. For position independent code one would fix `IP` at link time and choose `CS` at runtime.

It was not until the 386 and operating systems that used a 32-bit flat memory model that reading `IP` was useful for position independent code.

Answer (score 0):

A readable PC may require extra hardware resources, perhaps a dedicated set of unidirectional wires from the PC to some write Dest reg data path. Fetching instructions and pushing the PC only requires wires from the PC to the memory access unit.

So why add wires to the chip area budget unless there’s profitable payback (performance, etc.)

Comment: The "wires" to put the PC register on the ALU bus already exist even on the 8086, see e.g. the [patent](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/a0/d1/78/af97497890aca8/US4449184.pdf).

Answer (score -1):

It does. `call 1f; 1:` is "push ip".

Comment: This was already mentioned in [supercat’s answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/24525/79).

Comment: @wizzwizz4: Calling to a label immediately after the call instruction does not change the flow of execution but pushes the address immediately after the call instruction (the new value of ip) onto the stack (as the "return address").

Comment: @wizzwizz4: Nothing to do with linker. It's just how you write a call with zero displacement in asm mnemonics.